# "Error: Unable to access jarfile" in GitHub Actions when executing via .NET, but works from command line

Tags: java, c#, .net, github-actions, liquibase

I have a database with its schema managed using [Liquibase](https://docs.liquibase.com/home.html). I have a .NET application that uses that database for persistence. I have integration tests that use [Testcontainers](https://dotnet.testcontainers.org/). So when those tests run each test suite gets its own MySQL database, via Docker, to run its tests against and then those databases get terminated.

Liquibase does not have a native integration with .NET, so to run the database migrations I am calling out to the Liquibase CLI from .NET after the Testcontainers are available. This works perfectly locally, but I am having issues when I try to put this together in GitHub Actions:

```yaml
jobs:
  build-app:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 5
    steps:
    - name: Configure AWS CLI
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v4
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        aws-region: eu-west-2
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: Setup .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v4.0.0
      with:
        dotnet-version: 6.0.x
    - name: Setup Java
      uses: actions/setup-java@v2
      with:
        distribution: 'adopt'
        java-version: '11'
    - name: Install Liquibase
      run: |
        mkdir liquibase
        chmod +w liquibase
        wget https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/releases/download/v4.26.0/liquibase-4.26.0.tar.gz
        tar -xzf liquibase-4.26.0.tar.gz -C liquibase
        echo "LIQUIBASE_HOME=${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/liquibase/liquibase" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        
        chmod -R 755 liquibase
        
        liquibase/liquibase --version
    - name: Login to AWS CodeArtifact
      run: |
          aws codeartifact login --tool dotnet --repository ${{ secrets.AWS_CODEARTIFACT_REPOSITORY }} --domain ${{ secrets.AWS_CODEARTIFACT_DOMAIN }} --domain-owner ${{ secrets.AWS_CODEARTIFACT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER }}
    - name: Restore
      uses: cake-build/cake-action@v2
      with:
        target: Restore
    - name: Build
      uses: cake-build/cake-action@v2
      with:
        target: Build-CI
        arguments: |
          versionNumber: ${{inputs.version}}
    - name: Configure AWS CLI
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v4
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.INTEGRATION_RUNNER_AWS_ACCESS_KEY }}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.INTEGRATION_RUNNER_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        aws-region: eu-west-2
        role-to-assume: ${{ secrets.INTEGRATION_RUNNER_ROLE_ARN }}
    - name: Run tests
      uses: cake-build/cake-action@v2
      with:
        target: Test-CI
```

The call to `liquibase/liquibase --version` in the *Install Liquibase* step runs well, so I know Liquibase is installed correctly. However, once I call out to Liquibase from .NET I get the following error:

```bash
Error: Unable to access jarfile /home/runner/work/MyProject/WorkingDirectory/liquibase/liquibase/internal/lib/liquibase-core.jar
```

This file exists, so it is not a path issue. The .NET code that is doing that is:

```cs
private void RunLiquibaseChangesets()
    {
        const string changelog = "db/root-changelog.xml";
        var (username, password, databaseName) = DeconstructConnectionString(_dbContainer.GetConnectionString());
        var url = $"jdbc:mysql://localhost:{_dbContainer.GetMappedPublicPort(ContainerPortNumber)}/{databaseName}";
        var arguments =
            $"update --url={url} --username={username} --password={password} --changeLogFile={changelog} --contexts=test-data";
        var fileName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LIQUIBASE_HOME") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException(
            "LIQUIBASE_HOME environment variable not set. Please set it to the liquibase installation directory.");
        var rootDirectory = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GITHUB_WORKSPACE") ??
                            Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "..", "..", "..", "..", "..");

        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = fileName,
            Arguments = arguments,
            WorkingDirectory = rootDirectory,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };

        using var process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();

        // Use StringBuilder to capture output
        var outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        var errorBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        // Handle the output events
        process.OutputDataReceived += (_, args) => outputBuilder.AppendLine(args.Data);
        process.ErrorDataReceived += (_, args) => errorBuilder.AppendLine(args.Data);

        // Start reading output and error asynchronously
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.BeginErrorReadLine();

        var exited = process.WaitForExit(10000);
        
        Console.WriteLine("----------------- Liquibase Output Start -----------------");
        Console.WriteLine(outputBuilder.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("----------------- Liquibase Output End -----------------");
        
        Console.WriteLine("----------------- Liquibase Error Start -----------------");
        Console.WriteLine(errorBuilder.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("----------------- Liquibase Error End -----------------");

        // Check to see if the process has exited.
        if (!exited)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Process did not exit: Output: {outputBuilder} Error: {errorBuilder}");
        }
    }
```

I suspect it is permissions, but I have given full permissions via `chmod` so I am stuck as to what to try next.

Comment: _Does_ that file exist? Shouldn't it be `liquibase/internal` rather than `liquibase/liquibase/internal`, i.e. the `LIQUIBASE_HOME` is wrong? `liquibase/liquibase --version` succeeding tells you `liquibase/liquibase` is an executable, not a directory (`internal` is a _sibling_ of that executable).

Comment: @jonrsharpe - thanks. You pushed me in the right direction. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that `LIQUIBASE_HOME` has some special meaning to Liquibase even though it is not listed anywhere I can find. So I resolved this by using `LIQUIBASE_INSTALL_DIR` instead.

Thanks to [@jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) for nudging me in the right direction.